# Implementing a neural network to figure out its cost

Tags: matlab, neural-network

[Cost function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74YnB.png)

I am trying to code the above expression in Matlab. Unfortunately I seem to be getting a cost of 10.441460 instead of 0.287629 so I'm out by a factor of over 36!

As for each of the symbols:

```
m is the number of training examples.   [a scalar number]

K is the number of output nodes.   [a scalar number]

y is the vector of training outputs   [an m by 1 vector]


y^{(i)}_{k} is the ith training output (target) for the kth output node.   
[a scalar number]
x^{(i)} is the ith training input.   [a column vector for all the input 
nodes]
h_{\theta}(x^{(i)})_{k} is the value of the hypothesis at output k, with 
weights theta, and training input i.   [a scalar number]

note: h_{\theta}(x^{(i)}) will be a column vector with K rows.
```

My attempt for the cost function:

```
Theta1 = [ones(1,size(Theta1,2));Theta1];
X = [ones(m,1) , X];     %Add a column of 1's to X
R=zeros(m,1);
for i = 1:m
    a = y(i) == [10 1:9];
     R(i) = -(a*(log(sigmoid(Theta2*(sigmoid(Theta1*X(i,:)'))))) + (1-a)*(log(1-sigmoid(Theta2*(sigmoid(Theta1*X(i,:)'))))))/m;
end
J = sum(R);
```

This will probably be useful for reference:

```
  function [J grad] = nnCostFunction(nn_params, ...
                                   input_layer_size, ...
                                   hidden_layer_size, ...
                                   num_labels, ...
                                   X, y, lambda)

Theta1 = reshape(nn_params(1:hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1)), ...
                 hidden_layer_size, (input_layer_size + 1));

Theta2 = reshape(nn_params((1 + (hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1))):end), ...
                 num_labels, (hidden_layer_size + 1));

% Setup some useful variables
m = size(X, 1);


% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
% Instructions: You should complete the code by working through the
%               following parts.
%
% Part 1: Feedforward the neural network and return the cost in the
%         variable J. After implementing Part 1, you can verify that your
%         cost function computation is correct by verifying the cost
%         computed in ex4.m
%

% =========================================================================

end
```

Comment: Your `for` statement has no `end`, it will not run this way. Please paste correct, full code. What is the meaning of `a` in your function?

Comment: @CrisLuengo It runs the same whether or not I end the for statement but I have edited the code as suggested. I introduced `a` as a dummy variable, which takes on a vector of length `K` and is a vector of zeros except from where there is a `1` corresponding to the different training outputs: `10,10,..1,...,9,...9`.                                            
 `10` is used instead of `0` as Matlab does not index from `0`.

Comment: If the code ran, it was using the `end` that corresponds to `function` as corresponding to `for` (because `function` doesn't really need an `end`). That means that the `J=sum(R)` bit was part of the loop!

Comment: But you say that "y^{(i)}_{k} is the ith training output (target) for the kth output node." You are replacing that with `a`, which is a boolean matrix that assumes `K` is 10, but needs to match the length of `X(i,:)`, which is of the length of the number of input nodes, not `K`. Why don't you write this as a double loop first, to see if you can reproduce the correct output, before trying to optimize with dot products with boolean matrices? I bet the double loop will be faster too, since in your code you are computing the same sigmoid function twice.

Comment: It works if I have `a = y(i) == 1:10` instead of `a = y(i) ==[10 1:9]`, apologies the exercise document could have been clearer. I suppose if `J=sum(R)` is in the loop it makes the calculation slower?